# How to compare map and object using kotest?

Tags: kotlin, kotest

There is a class:

```
data class A(
    var id: Long = 0,
    var date: String? = null,
    var age: Long,
    var sex: String? = null,
    var city: String? = null
)
Object: val obj = A(id = 5, age = 22, sex = "male", city = "Example city")
```

There is a map:

```
val map = mapOf("age" to 22, "city" to "Example city")
```

How to compare map and object using kotest, so that they are equal?

Comment: I don't think there's a native way to compare a data class with a map that has its properties as keys. What you can do is convert it to Json and compare Jsons, or turn it to a map and compare both maps.

Answer (score 0):

@LeoColman proposes conversion to JSON which would give a generic solution.

If you want a non-generic solution:

```
import io.kotest.matchers.maps.shouldMatchExactly

        map.shouldMatchExactly(
            "id" to { it shouldBe obj.id },
            "date" to { it shouldBe obj.date },
            "age" to { it shouldBe obj.age },
            "sex" to { it shouldBe obj.sex },
            "city" to { it shouldBe obj.city },
        )
```

Ref: https://kotest.io/docs/assertions/core-matchers.html